# JW Player popup with s2member & amazon s3/cloudfront

Tags: amazon, s2member

I have been working on Developing a Tutorial site. I am using WordPress, ACF, s2member, amazon s3 & cloudfront and JW Player.

I have integrated amazon cloudfront with s2member but now I am having problem to play video in JW Player. I actually want to open the video player in a new window. I am going to use a custom post type for tutorials. Then custom field for Video name & links.

Can anybody help me find a way to play the video in a new window. Here is an exact demo of what I need to do :
http://www.vtc.com/products/MasterClass!-Cinema-4D-Lite-in-Adobe-After-Effects-CC-Workflow-Tutorials.htm

If you click on Input Devices, you will see the video open in a new window.

Here is my site : http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/courses/photoshop-course-1/

And here is my single-courses.php ::

```
get_header('courses'); ?>



    <?php

    /* Run the loop to output the posts.

     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file

     * called loop-single.php and that will be used instead.

     */

    the_post();


    //get_template_part('loop', 'single');

    ?>

<div class="course_details_box">
     <?php do_action('icl_language_selector'); ?>
    <table>
        <?php if(get_field('introduction')) : ?>
        <tr><h2>Introduction</h2></tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Files</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while(has_sub_field('introduction')) : ?>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:;" id="introduction<?php the_sub_field('sl._no.'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></a></td>
            <td><a rel="shadowbox" href="#introduction<?php the_sub_field('sl._no.'); ?>"><img src="http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Play-Button.png" class="play_btn" width="20"/></a></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('duration'); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <!--div id="#introduction<?php the_sub_field('sl._no.'); ?>" class="">
            <?php
// Configuration.
$s2_jw_config["jwplayer"] = "/jwplayer/"; // Relative URL path to JW Player files directory.
$s2_jw_config["mp4_video_file_name"] = get_sub_field("video_link"); // Name of your MP4 test file.
// Don't edit anything else below unless you know what you're doing.
?>

<div id="jw-container">JW Player® appears here.</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $s2_jw_config["jwplayer"]; ?>jwplayer.js"></script>

<?php // A direct URL to the RTMP source; counting the file against the current User in real-time.
$cfg = array ("file_download" => $s2_jw_config["mp4_video_file_name"], "url_to_storage_source" => true, "count_against_user" => true); ?>

<?php // API Function `s2member_file_download_url()` returns false if access is denied to the current User.
if (($mp4 = s2member_file_download_url ($cfg, "get-streamer-array"))) { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('jw-container').setup({
                playlist:
                    [{
                        sources: // List all available sources.
                            [
                                {type: 'rtmp', file: '<?php echo $mp4["streamer"]; ?>/mp4:<?php echo $mp4["file"]; ?>'},
                                {type: 'mp4', file: '<?php echo $mp4["url"]; ?>'}
                            ]
                    }],
                primary: 'flash' /* Try Flash® RTMP first, fallback on HTML5 or direct download of MP4 file. */,
                width: 480, height: 270 // Set video dimensions for all sources.
            });
    </script>

<?php } else /* Access is denied to the current User. */ { ?>
    Sorry, you do NOT have access to this file.
<?php } ?>
        </div -->
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>

        <!-- Basic Part -->
        <?php if (current_user_is("s2member_level1")){ ?>
        <?php if(get_field('basic_tutorial')) : ?>
        <tr><td><h2>Basic</h2></td></tr>


        <?php while(has_sub_field('basic_tutorial')) : ?>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('video_link'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('video_link'); ?>"><img src="http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Play-Button.png" class="play_btn" width="20"/></a></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('duration'); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
<?php if(get_field('basic_tutorial')) : ?>
        <tr><td><h2>Basic</h2></td></tr>


        <?php while(has_sub_field('basic_tutorial')) : ?>

        <tr>
            <td><span title="You must be a premium user to view this tutorial"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></span></td>
            <td><img title="You must be a premium user to view this tutorial" src="http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Play-Button.png" class="play_btn" width="20"/></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('duration'); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
    <?php } ?>

        <!-- Advanced Part -->
        <?php if (current_user_is("s2member_level1")){ ?>
        <?php if(get_field('advanced')) : ?>
        <tr><td><h2>Advanced</h2></td></tr>

        <?php while(has_sub_field('advanced')) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4<?php //the_sub_field('video_link'); ?>',
'welcome','scrollbars=yes,location=no, toolbar=no')"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php the_sub_field('video_link'); ?>"><img src="http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Play-Button.png" class="play_btn" width="20"/></a></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('duration'); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
    <?php } else { ?>

    <?php if(get_field('advanced')) : ?>
        <tr><td><h2>Advanced</h2></td></tr>

        <?php while(has_sub_field('advanced')) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><span title="You must be a premium user to view this tutorial"><?php the_sub_field('name'); ?></span></td>
            <td><img title="You must be a premium user to view this tutorial" src="http://demo.mamb2b.us/training/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Play-Button.png" class="play_btn" width="20"/></td>
            <td><?php the_sub_field('duration'); ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
</div> <!-- /.course-detials-box -->

<div class="course_right_part">
    <div class="course_desc">
        <h2>Course Description:</h2>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    </div>
    <?php //comments_template(); ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[facebookall_comments]'); ?>
<!--      <input type="text" width="" value="Post comment using your facebook account" />
 --></div>
<?php get_footer('courses'); ?>
```

Thanks in Advance for your Help!

Comment: Please ask me if you have any question about my requirement. I am checking it always..

Comment: Can you achieve this in proof of concept fashion sans WP bits? What do you _need_ to happen to have it work with JW Player, since it has little to do with WP by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this in a way. I am going to share how I have fixed if it helps someone else ..

I have created a new page template & page call Play Video where I have called empty header, footer & body section. Only the s2member function for playing video with jwplayer. I kept the video link to use GET method.

Then, From Single courses page, I have linked the videos with mysite.com/video/?video_name=myvideo.mp4 & an onclick function to open the page in a new window..